# Inserting data into memory table

Tags: mysql, memory-table

I have created a MEMORY table. I want to load the data from my MyIsam table (say `PIN_DETAILS`) into MEMORY table (say `PIN_DETAILS_MEMORY`).

When I try to dump the data of `MyISAM` table into MEMORY table (using `INSERT INTO...SELECT`), only *8190* rows get copied into the memory table. I have nearly 2 lacs records into MyISAM table. I have also tried to change ***max_heap_table_size*** without any luck. Can you please suggest any solution?

UPDATE:

My SQL query to insert data is

```
INSERT INTO PIN_DETAILS_MEMORY (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4 FROM PIN_DETAILS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be because of memory limitation consider using where condition before putting in to teporary table. Or consider using With Class

Comment: You were right. The memory limit was reached. I got error 1114. Alongwith your answer, this thread also helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793888/mysql-what-to-do-when-memory-tables-reach-max-heap-table-size?rq=1#